# Erlang: reverse search in binaries

Tags: string, erlang

Is there an analogue to `string:rstr()` for binaries?

I am also puzzled by the fact that while the proposal [EEP-9](http://erlang.org/eeps/eep-0009.html) suggesting implementing this within `binary_string` module was adopted for R12B-2 the current [OTP docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/) do not mention this module at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [binary:match](http://erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html#match-2) instead. `binary:match` will return  first occurrence of Pattern in Subject and the position and length in a tuple.But we should notice that `string:rstr` returns the first occurrence of Pattern begins in Subject.